# Vitamio: UnsatisfiedLinkError ,Native method not found

Tags: android, android-ndk, native-code, unsatisfiedlinkerror, vitamio

Hi I'm developing android application using Vitamio for playing live audio stream. When I installed the application in Sony Experia J(android 4.1.2) first time, it crashed. But when i opened it again, it started playing. So whenever i install the app for first time, the radio crashes in this device. Below is the crash log:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: 

io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer.native_init:()V
                at io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer.native_init(Native Method)
                at io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:238)
                at io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:192)
```

Getting the crash at this line:

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(this);
```

But not getting this crash when I debug the application. So not getting the exact reason for this crash.

I know this crash occurs, when it's not able to find the library. But, When I start the app again, it plays normally. Only whe I install the new build, app crashes with the above excepton.

Does anyone know, why this is happening..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning unable to catch this while debugging, that is because of while debugging, it is way **SLOWER**, than not to. So a simple and dirty fix would be just setup a delay.

The root cause is: while invoking a native method, the library is supposed to loaded-already (through System.loadLibrary()).

So my best guess is MediaPlayer.native_init is invoked before it's actually loaded while doing a first time through.

Solution: checkout where it loads the .so library and make the The MediaPlayer is initiated after the loading.

Answer (score 1):

If you use call
        `Vitamio.isInitialized(this);`

in `MyApplication extend Application` to initialize path of ****.so

I hope this tip can help you to fix your problem